# Disable c assertion in pthread library

Tags: c, crash, pthreads, assertion

i have a systematic random crash in pthread library ( indirectly used ):

**` Mutex - > __ .__ date owner == 0 ' failed .**

can i disable this assertion ? I would prefer a simple crash with a core generation to simplify debugging. With this assertion is hard to understand the crash point.

I have tried **add_definitions (-DNDEBUG)** to my CMakeList but the assertion remain.

Comment: Alternative: Is it possible to have an assertion failure trigger a core dump?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does crash at the assertion, but OP is wishing it would crash at the point OP's code actually first invoked UB. That's often hard to do, but tools like valgrind, ASan, UBSan, etc. can sometimes help.

Comment: @R., It is crashing, but it isn't producing a core dump. The OP wants a core dump so they can get a stack trace and/or to examine data structures as they existed at the time of the assertion. That said, those tools may also be useful.

Comment: Is it possible that core dumps are just disabled? What happens if the program is run under gdb to begin with? Most modern systems disable core dumps by default because their creation is a perpetual source of security bugs.

Comment: Failed assertions should normally lead to a core dump due to `assert` raising a `SIGABORT`. I'd guess that is done, and core dumps for this signal are simply not enabled on your system.

Answer (score 3):

No, and you don't want to. The assertion is not your problem, and disabling it would just allow the runaway wrong behavior to propagate even further away from its cause. The fact that you've clobbered memory that doesn't belong to you is your problem. Use valgrind or similar tools to try to track down what you did wrong rather than hoping you can just pretend it didn't happen.